# Преобразование ArrayList из String в Integer

Tags: java, jsoup

есть код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String HTMLString = "<!DOCTYPE html>"
            + "<html>"
            + "<head>"
            + "<title>JSoup Example</title>"
            + "</head>"
            + "<body>"
            + "<table><tr><td><h1>0</h1></tr>"
            + "<table><tr><td><h1>1</h1></tr>"
            + "</table>"
            + "</body>"
            + "</html>";

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(HTMLString);
    Elements elements = doc.select("body");

    ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Element i: elements)
        myList.add(Integer.parseInt(i.text()));

}
```

после компиляции выдает:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0 1"
```

В чем дело, никак не пойму? Если в HTML-коде одна строка, компиляция проходит успешно.

Comment: Он парсит элемент в одну строку "0 1". В итоге при парсе, парсер не знает про пробел. и вы получаете исключение. Нужно еще сделать split(" ")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`doc.select("body")` возвращает вам один элемент `body`, содержащий текст "0 1", который нельзя преобразовать в число. Попробуйте заменить на `doc.select("h1");`